# How to Store data to mySql database automatically after a certain time period using java?

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, arduino

I am creating a website (JSP based) that will show a graph based on data from a mysql table. The problem is, the data to be stored is based on a WSN (wireless sensor network), which is going to send the data once every hour. So i have to store the data every hour. How should I do this ? I need the data stored into the MySql table every hour automatically.

Thanks.

Comment: One suggestion is that you need to create rest service that is called with data periodically, from that you can store data in table.

Comment: Better to user Spring Quartz framework and in terms of submit data use REST will give you move rich granularity to your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Your functionality,

You should use TimerTask class(available in java.util package). TimerTask is a abstract class.
use public void run() method  to execute periodically.

You can check here.[How to run a task periodically in Java](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-run-a-task-periodically-in-java/)